# Publishing to Github Pages

Tags: github-actions, github-pages, worker

I am currently working on setting up a workflow for my Github Pages site. I have successfully created html files from Python and now only need to publish. I am using [this Github Action](https://github.com/crazy-max/ghaction-github-pages) for doing that. However, my builds fail with the error message:

> github-pages 222 | Error:  No such file or directory @ rb_check_realpath_internal - /github/workspace/bin/python3

I have the file /bin/python3 in my repository and it should additionally not be used for that build shouldnt it?
Why is it getting used and how do I fix it?

*Note: I am not limited to this specific action. If there is another one that works better I would be happy to use it!*

This is my worker file right now:

```
name: Jekyll site CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ gh-pages ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ gh-pages ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2.4.0

  - name: install python
    uses: actions/setup-python@v2
    with:
      python-version: "3.9.2"
 
  - name: install python packages
    run: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install jinja2
     
  - name: run python script
    run: python app.py
  
  - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
    if: success()
    uses: crazy-max/ghaction-github-pages@v2.5.0
    with:
      build_dir: ./
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Can you share your workflow file?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  I have the same issue and am completely stumped